# MongooseServerSelectionError when trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas from Node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, whitelist

I am building a Node.js application using Mongoose to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. However, when I try to run the application using nodemon, I am getting a MongooseServerSelectionError with the message 'Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster'. The error suggests that I might not be accessing the database from an IP that is whitelisted in my Atlas cluster. I have checked my IP address and it is included in the IP whitelist. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it

I have checked my IP address and it is on the whitelist of my MongoDB Atlas cluster. I also confirmed that I am able to connect to the cluster using the MongoDB Compass application. However, when I try to run my Node.js application with nodemon, I still get the MongooseServerSelectionError. I was expecting the application to connect to the database successfully, but instead, the error message is displayed. I tried running the application without nodemon, restarting my computer, and double-checking my connection string, but none of these steps resolved the issue.